# How to change the indentation of all enumerates?

Tags: lists, indentation

I want to indent enumerated items more. However every method I found deals with a single item in a list. How do I do this globally?

Comment: You use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). See section **5 Global settings** (p 9) of the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: @Werner Are there other ways to do this? "enumitem" conflicts with the "enumerate" package I'm using right now.

Comment: What are you using the `enumerate` package for?

Comment: @hyh All (one) feature of the `enumerate` package is provided by `enumitem` as well.

Comment: @NathanaelFarley  
I use the enumerate package because I need to use different numberings for the list, like a), b), c) or (i), (ii), (iii). (Texifying something old.) Can this be done with the other packages you suggested?

Comment: @tohecz See above, if `enumitem` can do that I will switch to that.

Comment: Mm, I'm pretty sure you can achieve that effect with `paralist` as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One crude method is to modify the definition of `\item` as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\itemold\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\itemindent10cm\itemold}

\begin{document}

Text
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But this is going to give you probably unwanted behaviour with nested lists.  Also, as you experience it affects a number of other enviroments, that naivly seem to have nothing to do with lists, since LaTeX internally uses a `trivlist` environment as a basic building block for environment formatting.

I would advise you to switch entirely over to `paralist` or `enumitem` instead, for example as described below.

### Paralist

With `paralist` you use the command `\setdefaultleftmargin`, which takes 6 arguments for the relative indents of the lists at levels 1 to 6.  **When using the optional argument to `enumerate`, it turns out that you also have to specify one of the label adjustment options to the package, otherwise these margin changes will be ignored.  (This looks like a bug in the otherwise well-tried package.)**

[image: Sample paralist output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[neverdecrease]{paralist}

\begin{document}

Test --- standard margins.
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item One
\item Two
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item Sub
  \end{enumerate}
\item Three
\end{enumerate}

\setdefaultleftmargin{8cm}{2cm}{}{}{}{}
Test --- changed margins.
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item One
\item Two
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item Sub
  \end{enumerate}
\item Three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

### enumitem

Here you need to load the package with the `shortlabels` option to get `enumerate`'s syntax for the specification of the labels.  The `\setlist` command is used to adjust default parameters for different lists and you can specify which levels they apply to.  For example, `\setlist[enumerate,1]` will apply to enumerates at level 1.  Providing an argument of the form `{leftmargin=10cm}` will then change the given left margin.

[image: Sample enumitem output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Test --- standard margins.
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item One
\item Two
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item Sub
  \end{enumerate}
\item Three
\end{enumerate}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=10cm}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=2cm}
Test --- changed margins.
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item One
\item Two
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item Sub
  \end{enumerate}
\item Three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The `enumitem` package is newer has many more facilities than the lighter weight `paralist`.  It provides powerful and easy control over all types of list formatting.

Note the spacing in the `paralist` and `enumitem` examples is different, as there are some slightly different package defaults.

Comment: That works! However, \proof is also indented. Any fix of this?

Comment: I use the enumerate package because I need to use different numberings for the list, like a), b), c) or (i), (ii), (iii). (Texifying something old.) Can this be done with the other packages you suggested?

Comment: Absolutely, both packages provide such facilities.  `paralist`'s syntax is exactly as `enumerate`'s for this change, but you can also set defaults in a nice way.  `enumitim` has a package option `shortlabels` emulating the `enumerate` syntax.

Comment: The problem with `\proof` is not so unexpacted.  LaTeX uses lists in all sorts of strange places to build various constructions that you wouldn't expect.  That is way using one of the other packages is strongly recommended for such changes.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and switched to `paralist`. However, the method described in the other answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have now provided details by extending my answer.

Comment: The link you provide does not work.  But the correct parameter for this ought to be `\listparindent` - however, that does not work with `enumerate` or `paralist`.  Either you have set `\parindent` explicitly in each list, or use `enumitm` which allows to specify `\listparindent` directly.

Comment: Just one last question, see [here](http://goo.gl/8lXhy). Is there a way to get rid of the space between `1.1.3` and `a)` while the indent of `b)` remain unchanged?

Comment: It is better to start a new line here, e.g. wihh `\leavevmode`.

Comment: Thanks. So there is not even a dirty way to do this?

Comment: We shouldn't really be using to comments for this, new questions ought to be asked as such.  However with `paralist`: `\begin{example}
  \begin{inparaenum}
  \item One\par
  \item Two
  \end{inparaenum}
\end{example}`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `paralist` package to set the default left margins of lists/enumerates/etc. Simply use the command `\setdefaultleftmargin` like so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumerate} %% to check paralist doesn't clash
\begin{document}
This is a test
\begin{enumerate}
\item This
\item is
\item a
\item list
\end{enumerate}

\setdefaultleftmargin{0pt}{}{}{}{}{}
This is a test
\begin{enumerate}
\item This
\item is
\item a
\item list
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find a description of `\setdefaultleftmargin` [here](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/paralist.pdf).

Comment: I'm trying to switch to the paralist package. But `\setdefaultleftmargin` doesn't work for me at all. I tried to put in all kinds of lengths but nothing changes. A command like `\setdefaultleftmargin{1em}{2.2em}{1.8em}{3pt}{1em}{1cm}` doesn't give me any change.

Comment: It's possible that other packages are conflicting with it. Which others are you using? It could help to put `paralist` last, so that it overwrites the behaviour of any other packages you've loaded.

If that doesn't work, where do you put `\setdefaultleftmargin`? Try it inside the `\begin{document}` if you can, again it may be another package changing the settings once `\begin{document}` is processed.

Comment: And if niether of those work, a MWE of it not working would be a great help!

Comment: `\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\nc{\up}{\usepackage}

\up[hmargin=1.2cm, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\up{amsfonts} 
\up{amsmath} 
\up{amsthm} 
\up{amssymb}
\up{xspace}
\up[all]{xy}
\up{ulem}% \uuline for double uline

\up{extarrows}

\up{paralist}

\up[utf8]{inputenc}
\up[T1]{fontenc}

\up{titlesec}`

Comment: What does MWE mean?

Comment: Even putting it inside the document doesn't help.