# How can I align my list?

Tags: formatting, lists

How can I format my list like this?

[image]

See how the list begins right under 0. I want to know how to start a list there. The indent is 0.5 if thats needed.

I have a code already but the list is not lined up and it has to be lined up. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}  
\begin{document}  


\noindent   
Let \textit{f} be a function given by \textit{f}(\textit{x})= $\displaystyle cos\bigg(2x+ \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{6}\bigg)$ and let \textit{P}(\textit{x}) be the fourth-degree Taylor polynomial about \textit{f} at \textit{x}=0.  
\vspace{.01in}  


\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]  
\item Find \textit{P}(\textit{x}). \textbf{(4)}  

\end{enumerate}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add the code of a small complete document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that illustrates the problem. Just use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/346938/edit).

Comment: In general, labels are right-aligned, which goes a bit counter to what you are asking.  However, `leftmargin` is an optional argument that can be used with `enumitem` to allocate the space to the beginning of the actual item ("Find" in your example).

Comment: Did you ever hear of math mode to typeset maths formulae? Using `\textit` *ad libitum* is exhausting (and the spacing will be bad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steven and [the first comment to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97305/how-to-change-the-indentation-of-all-enumerates) point out, check out page 9 of the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf). For the lazy, simply add the following line before `\begin{enumerate}`, adjusting the size as necessary:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=0.5in}
```